# PL/SQL INSERT Ignored statement

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor, oracle-sqldeveloper, sql-function

What I have to do is to INSERT in table "info" different content, depending on the select result: if it is *one row*, *no rows* or *more than one row*.
I want to set the outretvalue variable on the exception section, then do the insert in the IF section, depending on outretvalue value.
Anyway, I get an error at compiling saying that ***f2 function is in an invalid state. I have 2 errors: for the INSERT and for not recognising rowcount***. Why?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f2 (v_nume employees.last_name%TYPE DEFAULT 'Bell') 
RETURN NUMBER 
IS 
  salariu employees.salary%type; 
  outretvalue number(2) := 0;
BEGIN 
  SELECT salary 
  INTO salariu 
  FROM employees 
  WHERE last_name = v_nume; 
  RETURN salariu; 
  EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    outretvalue := 1;

  WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN
--at this row I have 2 errors: for the INSERT and for not recognising rowcount
    INSERT INTO info(`no_lines`) VALUES(SQL%ROWCOUNT);

END f2; 
/
SELECT f2('King') FROM dual;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function:

```
DECLARE
BEGIN
END;
   ... something
END;
```

Add another BEGIN at begin or move your IF inside existing BEGIN END block and remove second END.

EDIT: after clarification

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f2 (v_nume employees.last_name%TYPE DEFAULT 'Bell') 
RETURN NUMBER 
IS 
  salariu     employees.salary%type; 
  outretvalue number(2) := 0;
BEGIN 
  SELECT salary 
    INTO salariu 
    FROM employees 
   WHERE last_name = v_nume; 
  RETURN salariu; 
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    RETURN -1;
  WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN
    SELECT count(*)
      INTO salariu
      FROM employees 
     WHERE last_name = v_nume; 
    INSERT INTO info(no_lines) VALUES(salariu);
    RETURN -2;
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RETURN -3;
END f2; 
/

SET SERVEROUTPUT on

DECLARE
  l_ret  NUMBER;
BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line(f2('Bell'));
  dbms_output.put_line(f2('noBell'));
  dbms_output.put_line(f2('King'));
END;
```

Comment: i have removed the end between EXCEPTION block and IF block

Comment: Use SELECT count(*) in WHEN others section. But... you shold move INSERT into too_many_rows section, or it never executing cause  you have two consequence rows of code outretvalue := 3 AND if outretvalue = 2.

Comment: thank you, but it doesn t even get there. Because of my input, there will be TOO_MANY_ROWS, and the outretvalue will be 2. This is why it gets into the IF statement and throws error at INSERT(for some unknown reason)

Comment: And one more: if you get in any EXCEPTION section, function ends without return. It's a error.

Comment: OH. so to execute the insert depending in the no of rows, i have to not use exceptions at all?

Comment: EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    outretvalue := 1;
  WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS 
    THEN INSERT INTO info(`no_lines`) VALUES(4);

Comment: still getting 2 errors: at the word INSERT and at '4'

Comment: Read my edited answer and please always post error text.

Comment: Okay.
Error 1: SQL Statement ignored. (at the beginning of INSERT word)
Error 2: ORA-00911: invalid character (at '4')

Comment: I cant understand why you got invalid character error. Can you post full f2 text and also try my version of f2?

Comment: I have updated the description with the actual version of f2.

Comment: @Lulu ohh...1) why do you still using SQL%ROWCOUNT 2) what is these strange symbols around no_lines column name 3) where return clause in exception block 4) you cant use select f2 from dual if there DML inside function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97137/discussion-between-hinotf-and-lulu).

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this. It will definelty help you out.

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f2(
    v_nume employees.last_name%TYPE DEFAULT 'Bell')
  RETURN NUMBER
IS
  salariu employees.salary%type;
  outretvalue NUMBER(2) := 0;
  lv_cnt PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
  SELECT salary INTO salariu FROM employees WHERE last_name = v_nume;
  RETURN salariu;
EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
  outretvalue := 1;
WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN
  SELECT COUNT(1) INTO lv_cnt FROM employees WHERE last_name = v_nume;
  INSERT INTO info
    ( no_lines
    ) VALUES
    ( lv_cnt
    );
    RETURN 2;
WHEN OTHERS THEN
RETURN 3;
END f2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle saves the compile errors in a table.  I use the following query for retrieving the PL/SQL errors in my stored procs/funcs:

```
SELECT '*** ERROR in ' || TYPE || ' "' || NAME || '", line ' || LINE || ', position ' || POSITION || ': ' || TEXT
  FROM SYS.USER_ERRORS
```

You could try running it and see if it helps identify the error in the function.

Comment: Encountered the symbol "IF"